# Is Stack Overflow Enterprise suitable for in-house corporate expert communities?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

Everyone knows Stack Overflow is good for software developers. Is it good for other expert communities?

For example, are there successful examples of use as a corporate **Q&A platform for industrial engineers**?

The usage scenario looks similar: in-house experts would ask and answer engineering questions. Is there something that would make it not work efficiently?

Comment: I think questions about https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise should be asked at [meta.so].

Comment: Maybe. I'm new to asking questions here. Sorry if I ask it in a wrong place

Comment: There once was an (advertorial)blog about this subject: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/05/13/how-expensify-engineers-save-hours-each-week-with-stack-overflow-for-teams/